# Deleted /usr/bin/sudo

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, centos7

I was following [this](https://www.simplified.guide/redhat-centos/install-vim) guide for upgrading Vim in CentOS7.

After uninstalling `vim-minimal`, `/usr/bin/sudo` was removed for dependencies.

Is there a way for me to reinstall this without completely wiping my instance and starting from scratch?

Edit:
`su -` is disabled on EC2 instances, so it is not possible to switch to `root` and `yum install sudo`

Comment: Have you tried `yum install sudo`? You will probably have to elevate to root with `su -` and you might need to fix your sudoers file with `visudo`. Out of curiosity what command did you enter that caused you to delete sudo?

Comment: `yum remove -y vim-minimal` uninstalled `sudo` as a dependency. I can't `yum install sudo` without root, and `su -` doesn't work because it's an AWS therefore root without sudo is inaccessible (I think?).

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised that took removed sudo. I found this superuser question after googling for a bit: https://superuser.com/questions/1307214/uninstalling-vim-minimal-also-uninstalls-sudo-in-centos-7-4 `su -` is used to switch user to the root account, but if you don't have know the root password that's not very helpful for you. It may just be easier to create a new EC2 instance if you run out of things to try and you don't mind setting a new one up.